# Using enum type in Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, enums, constants

I have an enum typed declared in a class file called x and I would like to use it from another. This is an excerpt of my code

> enum Type {D,H,B,UNDEFINED}; //this line is inside x.java file

I would like to use that enum "Type" from another class file in the following way

```
   import <package>.x;  

   public void test(int param){
      if(param == D) do the following;   
      else do others;  
   }
```

is the package x.java belongs to. These two files are in the same package, so I'm not sure if it's necessary to explicitly mention that in import line. Anyway, Eclipse doesn't recognize D is a constant and suggesting me to create one. I've tried Type.D. but doesn't work. So how do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your java file with your enum the same way as your enum, ie. Type.java.

Add the import line.

You should be able to use the syntax (note, I changed the parameter type):

```
public void test(Type param){
  if(param == Type.D) do the following;   
  else do others;
```

}